# Deducing Protobuf Schema and Datatypes

Tags: file-format, python, encodings, protocol

I have a number of protobuf files but no .proto schema file!

`cat myfile.pbuf | protoc --decode_raw > outputfile.txt`

Using the above command, I was able to decode the file into a somewhat readable protobuf format ([Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898230/decoding-protobuf-without-schema)):

```
1: 1
2: ""
2 {
  1: 0x40133f7ced916873
  2: 0x3ff70e5604189375
  3: 0xbfd23d70a3d70a3d
  4: 0x3fb999999999999a
}
2 {
  1: 0x4022e7ef9db22d0e
  2: 0x4006ed916872b021
  3: 0xbfe1cac083126e98
  4: 0x3fc999999999999a
}
2 {
  1: 0x402bdcac083126e9
  2: 0x40111374bc6a7efa
  3: 0xbfe9fbe76c8b4396
  4: 0x3fd3333333333333
}
2 {
  1: 0x40324147ae147ae1
  2: 0x401696872b020c4a
  3: 0xbff0e147ae147ae1
  4: 0x3fd999999999999a
}
...
```

I know without the schema I cannot know the meaning of these values, but I am wondering if there is anything else I can do to deduce what this strangeness is!  The [protobuf documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) seems to indicate that numerical data is served in 2 or 4 byte chunks, which I could easily convert to ints or floats.

My data does not fit into this format, but I know it to be numerical data!  I've never seen a protobuf file with the hex `x` notation, and there are 16 bytes (way too many for a single number!).

**What datatype might this be, is it possible to decode and further without the schema, and are the `1, 2, 3, 4` useful or significant?**

Comment: what is this capture from? do you have access to the code which parses it?

Comment: I am using the `--decode_raw` command from the `protoc` library, which attempts to decode a protobuf stream without a .proto schema.

Comment: yes, but where is the capture from? who(what) is sending the data and who is receiving?

Comment: "I know it to be numerical data" <- how do you know it? please provide as much info as possible.

Comment: The protobuf files are intended for a piece of proprietary software, which among other things, graphs the data in a time series.  The particular sample I provided corresponds to golf ball flight.  The `4:` seems to be a monotonic and increasing value (time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect these are IEEE doubles. For example, 0x3fd3333333333333 is 2.99999999999999988897769753748E-1, or around 0.3. I used [this converter](http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html?hexadecimal=3fd3333333333333) to check

Comment: Is there an easy method for conversion using python?

Comment: Figure it out - you are an absolute gem!!       `a = struct.unpack('>d', binascii.unhexlify(line[line.index('x')+1:-1]))`